# Overriding navbar-inverse style with LESS variables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to add some variables to my variables.less file that will allow me to override the navbar-inverse styling that is provided by Bootstrap. I have a normal navbar styled, but I cannot get the inverse to work.

Here's my navbar styling which works:

```
@navbar-default-color:            @white;
@navbar-default-bg:               @brand-primary;
@navbar-default-border:           @navbar-default-bg;
```

So I followed that example and tried to style the inverse with this:

```
@navbar-inverse-color:                      @brand-primary;
@navbar-inverse-bg:                         @white;
@navbar-inverse-border:                     @white;
```

But it doesn't work. Any reason why?

Comment: The above should work. Can you show you navbar's HTML too? Notice that you should use both the `navbar` and `navbar-inverse` classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more variables for the styling of the inverse navbar, but what you are doing should work just fine.

If you don't see the expected result, I would check the following:

- Are you recompiling the bootstrap.less file?
- Are those custom variables being improrted in your less file after the bootstrap variables (so they are in fact overwritten)
- You are not looking at a cached version of your css file?
- You have not overwritten your custom navbar elsewhere (should be easy to detect with the Inspector)
- You are applying the correct classes in your markup?

Those are the first things that come to mind. Let me know if this still doesn't resolve your issue, and I'll think deeper ;-)

Comment: The bootstrap.less file is getting recompiled, with the bootstrap variables being overwritten. At least, it's supposed to be and last I checked it was. Oddly enough, navbar-inverse is having some wonky issues in general for me (collapsing navbar isn't working either, doesn't push down page), so I have a feeling something is going wrong during compilation.